# Can't ping the machine via its host name, though I am able to ping via its ip address

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008

I am using Windows server 2008 & have iis7 installed. I enter the command `ping <hostname>` and I get the error: `Ping request could not find the host name.`

When I did `ipconfig -all`

```
"C:\Users\Administrator>ipconfig -all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Decisons_Win2008
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Network Connection
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-0C-29-F2-71-6A
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::61bc:3d4b:76d1:2387%11(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.168.167(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 12 July 2011 12:39:28
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 13 July 2011 12:39:27
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.168.168
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.168.168
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 234884137
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-15-A0-D6-B6-00-0C-29-DA-6F-43

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.19.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{11E5344A-7083-449F-B326-CECA5F7B43A3}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 9:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:4137:9e76:1cbf:e96:3f57:5758(Prefe
rred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::1cbf:e96:3f57:5758%13(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

Also when I enter the command hostname in the command prompt, I get the correct hostname. Still I am not able to ping the host name.
There were posts similar to the problem that I have, I have read those, still could not resolve the issue.

Updates:

@Mark I did not have the DNS server setup on that machine. So did the setup. Followed [this link](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/how-do-i-install-and-configure-a-dns-server-in-windows-server-2008/327), but seems that I could not configure that correctly.  So I'm stuck at the same place.

I am not a server admin guy, like most of you all so not quite clear with the options available like "Server names" & Host (A) records. looks like that's where things went wrong.

@ByITDesign I can't do that as I am not able to ping the server via its machine name for the same machine. I thought I had done that as well, but then realized that it would not be the right thing.
So for now I am accessing the server via IP address.

Answer (score 5):

The error message means it couldn't find a DNS entry for Decisons_Win2008.
You have a DNS server at 192.168.19.1 but it doesn't have an entry for Decisons_Win2008 in it.

What is living on 192.168.19.1? Is that a domain controller? If so then adding Decision_Win2008 to the domain should cause it to automatically update the A record in DNS. Otherwise you need to manually add it to the DNS server.

Answer (score 0):

Making the entry in host file on local desktop can also resolve this issue. Make changes in host file located here.
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

192.168.X.X  servername

Answer (score 0):

It may also be possible that your DHCP server 192.168.168.168 may also be providing you the DNS services, in which case you simply need to set your network settings to "Obtain a DNS server dynamically" from within your network adapter settings.  It will remove the DNS that you have defined.

Hope that it helps.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, I had to configure the **firewall** of my **Windows 2008 Server**:

- I had to go into *Start > Control Panel > Windows Firewall > Change Settings > tab "**Exceptions**" > check "**Network Discovery**"*.
- I had to enable ping requests/responses as well, as described **[here](http://patrickyong.wordpress.com/2008/05/04/enable-ping-replies-on-windows-server-2008/)**.